# How to compare two dates from MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a simple thing in PHP, but not run properly.
So, I need to compare two dates from MYSQL using PHP and show the oldest date, but the result in PHP is not correct.

I have this table in MYSQL DB:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id int,
    name varchar(255),
    date1 date,
    date2 date,
);

+---+---------------+------------+------------+
|id |name           |date1       |date2       |
+---+---------------+-------------------------+
|1  |ANA            |2005-02-27  |2004-03-27  |
+---+---------------+------------+------------+
|2  |MARIA          |2010-03-08  |2014-11-01  |
+---+---------------+-------------------------+
```

I'm using this PHP code:

```
$conn =  mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
$sql = "SELECT name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date2) FROM users ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";

echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>Name</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Date1</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Date2</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>Oldest Date</b></td>";
echo "<tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
      if (intval($row[1]) < intval($row[2])){
         echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
      } else {
         echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
      };
   };
   echo "</tr>";
};
echo "</table>";
```

It seems easy, but this statement of comparison do not return correctly. I just tried this ways below:

**1.** Using operator < (no correct return):

```
if ($row[1] < $row[2]) {...}
```

**2.** Using intval to force unix_timestamp to be Integer (no correct return):

```
if (intval($row[1]) < intval($row[2])) {...}
```

Any idea to resolv this question?
It is a simple comparison of dates (from fields of type DATE in MYSQL).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let de database handle it for you:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, date1, date2, IF(date1 < date2, date1, date2) FROM users";
```

Now `$row[3]` always contains the smallest date.

**[Edit]**

As OP only later mentioned the dates could also have a `NULL` value, the query needs adjusting. It now always returns the other date if one of the dates is empty, or `NULL` if both dates are empty.

```
SELECT id, date1, date2, 
  // test if one of the dates (or both) is NULL
  // if so return the one date, or NULL if both are empty
IF(date1 IS NULL OR date2 IS NULL, COALESCE(date1, date2),
  // else compare dates
IF(date1 < date2, date1, date2)
) FROM test
```

Comment: It is a good way, but I have NULL in some dates. In this case it always returns NULL. Is it possible to exclude NULL dates?

Comment: As you didn't make any mention of it in your original question, that should be a new question. But I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could return your dates the way they are stored (instead of converting to unix) and use a DateTime object to check the dates.

```
$sql = "SELECT name, date1, date2 FROM users";

...

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    //convert date1 string to DateTime object.
    $date1 = new \DateTime($row[1]);

    //convert date1 string to DateTime object.
    $date2 = new \DateTime($row[2]);

    //create a variable (using a Ternary) to hold the biggest date
    //Ternary means = (Expression) ? true : false
    $oldest_date = ($date1 > $date2) ? $date2 : $date1;

    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row[0] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row[1] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row[2] ?></td>
            <td><?= $oldest_date ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
}
```

- [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [Ternary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: `DateTime` is redundant here. OP seems to fetching the dates as UNIX timestamps anyway

Comment: Why do you need an object? You should compare ISO8601 date strings as strings. Besides as I said OP is fetching integers.

Comment: So this makes the question lacking debugging details